A graph in 3D space that is planar
question:
the graph $G=(V,E)$ is defined by: $V = \{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$ and the sets $E_1,E_2, E_3$ sets of edges so that $E = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup E_3$ and
$$E_1 = \{\{(a,b,c),(a+1,b,c)\} | 1\leq a \leq 2, 1 \leq b \leq 3, 1 \leq c \leq 3\}$$
$$E_2 = \{\{(a,b,c),(a,b+1,c)\} | 1\leq a \leq 3, 1 \leq b \leq 2, 1 \leq c \leq 3\}$$
$$E_3 = \{\{(a,b,c),(a,b,c+1)\} | 1\leq a \leq 3, 1 \leq b \leq 3, 1 \leq c \leq 2\}$$
Is $G$ planar?
Trying to solve this question, I know that the vertexes in the graph are defined as points in a 3D space and that $|E_1=|E_2|=|E_3|=2 \times 3 \times 3 = 18$ and that $|V|=27$. I thought you could use the fact that if $\forall v \in V deg(v) \geq 6$ the graph can't be planar, but I don't know how to find the degree of the vertexes. After skimming though the question, my friend said you could try to prove that's it's a polyhedron

Why is the graph disconnected? Unless I'm mistaken, the subgraph induced by all $(a,b,1)$ is a grid graph. Similarly for $c=2$ and $c=3$ we get grids, and the three grids are connected via edges $(a,b,1) \leftrightarrow (a,b,2) \leftrightarrow (a,b,3)$.

Ah, my mistake, I forgot that there are 3 sets in E. I edited the question

We can see that each vertex in the middle layer of the grid will have a degree of 6 since it is connected to its adjacent vertices in all six directions (up, down, left, right, forward, backward). Vertices on the faces but not at the edges of the grid will have a degree of 5, and vertices on the edges but not at the corners will have a degree of 4. The corner vertices will have a degree of 3.
It's not enough to use the fact a planar graph must have $deg(v) < 6$ for all vertexes $v$, But we can look for a subgraph that is holomorphic to $k_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. The graph doesn't contain any $K_5$ subgraphs but includes a $K_{3,3}$ subgraph if we look at any two parallel planes of the grid. Select two parallel planes and then choose three non-collinear vertices from each plane to see this. These vertices will form two sets of three vertices, and each vertex from one set is connected to all vertices of the other set by edges that go perpendicularly between the planes.
since we can find a subgraph that is holomorphic to $K_{3,3}$, by Kuratowski's theorem the graph is non-planar
